# ANDROID internal storage file delete/exist not working for me

Tags: android, file, storage, delete-file

First of all, I want to know if making a file without extension is okay. For example, making a file with ".txt" extendsion will make it a txt file on a computer, but I don't know it matters in android. And I noticed that when working on eclipse, I could deleted a fild with the extensions but couldn't delete a file without a extension.

I want my program to delete a file in the internal storage (com.name.application folder) but it's not working for me.

I make a file with

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

write with

```
bos = new BufferedOutpuStream(openFileOutput(FileName,Context.MODE_APPEND)
bos.write(newVocabFile.getBytes());
```

and I want to delete with

```
FILE file = new File(fileName);
fild.delete();
```

I did researches on google and applied different methods to my codes, but every method did not work for me. Because .delete() does not work properly, .exist() does not work either. I tired making the mile with and without extension but both ways did not work either.

I really need to get through this in order to finish my application. Please help me

Comment: Do you have the right permissions set in your manifest file? Also make sure you really mean internal storage. For example my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Tablet has its internal storage as sd card and it's considered external storage from the point of view of the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on this line

```
FILE file = new File(fileName);
fild.delete();
```

It should be

```
File file = new File(fileName);
file.delete();
```

Comment: thanks for correcting me but it was a typo for the answer. My code has the right code, but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you setting the correct permissions in your manifest file? `<manifest ...>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />     ... </manifest>`

Comment: Yes, I have all the permissions but it does not work. I should make a new project and try it.

Comment: My program deleted the files with content in it. Like when file.length() returns number greater than 0. But did not delete the files that had 0 size but still visible on DDMS file explorer